# Symfony2: Inserting collection form data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-components

There is a one-to-one relationship between `User` and `Company` entity.
When initializing (creating) the user's company, userID should be bind to Company user field as a foreign key. But instead of that, i get this error message:

> Property "id" is not public in class
>   "Website\CompanyBundle\Entity\User". Maybe you should create the
>   method "setId()"?

Why Symfony wants to create new User when this form is about Company entity, and User entity is just a collection that should provide user's ID.

Here is my code:

*Company.php entity*:

```
namespace Website\CompanyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Website\CompanyBundle\Entity\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

}
```

*CompanyType.php*

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->security= $security;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        $builder
        ->add('user', new UserType($security))
        ->add('company_name')
        ->add('company_address')
        ...
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Website\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

UserRelationType.php

```
class UserRelationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security){
        $this->user = $security->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', 'hidden', array('data' => $this->user->getId()))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Website\CompanyBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

*User.php entity*

```
namespace Website\CompanyBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $company;
}
```

Comment: provide your user entity please

Comment: added User entity, just an average User class with one-to-one relationship

Comment: you have missing getters/setters please see my answer to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You map entity to form in `UserRelationType`. On save it try to set id on user entity. You must specify [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) or use [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) if you need to select existed user.

If you want to set current user, better do it in event listener like [pre_persist](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#prepersist)

Comment: definitely valuable information, I recalled the "entity field type" solution in my bed last night, but prePersist seems to be the right solution for this problem (hope I will manage to do it right)

Comment: yeah forgottenbas provided nice information here, true ... you have fixed your missing setter as my solution suggested before, right?

Answer (score 2):

your properties in your entities are protected but you have not created getters/setters for them. ( or you have not pasted your full code )

Therefore the form-builder is not able to access your user's properties.

At least the `public function setId($id)` in User.php is definitely missing!

That's why the exception is thrown saying:

```
Maybe you should create the method "setId()"?
```

Create getters and settes for every property using ...

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

or create them by hand...

<kbd>User.php</kbd>

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem without adding collections and just using Doctrine transitive persistence like described in this page: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

*CompanyController.php*

```
public function createIndex(Request $request){
    $user = $this->getId();
    $company = new Company();

    if($user instanceof User){
        $company->setUser($user);
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $createForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyType(), $company);

    if('POST' === $request->getMethod())
    {
        $createForm->bindRequest($request);

        if($createForm->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($company);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help